# Filtering array of class gets: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have this class defined:

```
export class Contract {
    id:number;
    name:string;
    ....
}
```

In one of my components:

```
included_contracts: Contract[];

private includeSelectedContract(selected_contract: FormControl): void {
    let data:Contract = selected_contract.value as Contract    
    let is_exists = this.included_contracts.filter(c => c.id === data.id).length > 0 ? true : false;

    console.log(is_exists);
}
```

As per you can see that `included_contracts` is an array of class, im expecting this will do the same thing in older angular version for array of object behavior but i get the:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: how is the included_contracts variable initialized? The error suggests it's not.

Comment: @toskv thanks for a quick response i changed the `included_contracts: Contract[];` to `included_contracts: Contract[] = [];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have not initialized your `included_contracts` variable. Make sure you put some data in it before you call this method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the array

```
included_contracts: Contract[] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialise your array.
included_contracts: Contract[] = [];

or somewhere in your code.